# I want this script to trigger a javascript function instead of saying hello

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a script that works, now keep in mind that I don't really know JQuery at all. I want this script:

```
document.getElementById("id_of_button").onclick = function() {clickFunction()};

function clickFunction() {alert("hello");}

$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode === 13){
        $("#id_of_button").click();
    }
});
```

to trigger this function instead of creating a hello popup

```
document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)
```

Comment: You're asking how to use a text editor?

Comment: no, I want the jquery script to trigger the other function.

Comment: You already have that code. You can replace the alert with the code you need in `clickFunction`, or place it to `keyup` handler as well. Also it's possible to place it in a third function and call that function in `keyup` handler instead of `.click()`.

Comment: Include the line of code inside ` if(event.keyCode === 13){` if you want it on keyup with keycode `13` @Kallus

Comment: still won't work, just brings me to "search.html?" instead of doing the line of code

Comment: nothing i see works, i tried it all but it didnt work, it just goes to search.html? instead of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear but from the limited information:

```
function clickFunction() {
  var mylink = escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value);
  document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + mylink;
}
```

Looks like this entire thing can be written as:

```
$("#id_of_button").on('click', function() {
  var mylink = escape($('#search-box').value);
  document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + mylink;
});

$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    $("#id_of_button").trigger('click');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code what you want

```
<input type="text" id="search-box">
<button id="id_of_button">Search</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("id_of_button").onclick = function() {clickFunction()};

  function clickFunction() {
    document.location.href =
        'https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' +
      escape(document.getElementById('search-box').value)
    }

  $("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 13){
          $("#search-box").click();
      }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: it didn't work, just sends me to search.html? instead of the page I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#id_of_textbox").click(function () {
    document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape($('#search-box').val())
});

$(document).keypress(checkKey);

function checkKey(e) {
    switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 13:
       document.location.href = 'http://cse.google.com/cse?cx=009002930969338329916:kta6o_isob0&q=' + escape($('#search-box').val())
        break;
    }
}
```